# The column name was not found in this ResultSet

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, nativequery

I have a sub entity MyEntity that inherits properties from a mapped super class with an embedded id that has properties that don't exist in the table of my entity E as follows :

mapped super class :

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class MySuperClass implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ClassID id;
    //code
}
```

my id class

```
@Embeddable
public class ClassID implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Boolean frequency;
    private long defaultCustom;
    private String type;
//code
}
```

now this is my entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "My_Entity")
public class MyEntity extends MySuperClass implements Serializable {
    
}
```

here is my repository

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MySuperClass, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT  t.*, 0 as default_custom, null as type FROM My_Entity t  WHERE  t.id= :id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<MyEntity > getMyEntity(String id);
```

I am trying to create defaultCustom and type as alias because My_Entity does not have these columns and the id in the supper class needs to map them.

I am getting the following error :

```
The column name default was not found in this ResultSet.
could not execute query; SQL [SELECT...
```

here's my application.properties :

```
#POSTGRES
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=..url
spring.datasource.username=..username
spring.datasource.password=..pw
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.profiles.include=no-liquibase
spring.liquibase.enabled=false
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform.database=POSTGRES
```

I have tried the solutions out there but none of them work unfortunately and I can't change the model and the inheritance so I need to find a workaround for this problem. any suggestions?

Comment: Never ever use * in production code. You have no idea what data to expect

Comment: Thank you for you remark Frank, well noted!

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm your intentions. By putting those 5 fields into your class annotated @Embeddable, you are saying that it takes the combination of all 5 to uniquely identify instances of mySuperClass (which by the way should be MySuperClass).

But your repository definition and implementation contradicts that: public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<mySuperClass, Long>.
If you intended to define a composite primary key, your repository would be public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<mySuperClass, ClassID>
That is, "This JPA repository operates upon instances of mySuperClass identified by instances of ClassID"
But not so! Your SQL query makes it clear that the id column alone is unique, or intended to be.

I think you can ditch the @Embeddable and @EmbeddedId. Ditch the ClassID class altogether, put its fields in mySuperClass and annotate @Id private String id; (or private Long id, to match your repository declaration)

Let me know if that puts you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I actually can not change the structure of the class that's why I have to find a workaround solution for this problem. the id column is not unique!